# AES Crypto from Java to C#

Tags: java, c#, encryption, aes

I have this code in Java and i have success with encrypt the string.

```
public AESCrypt(String password) throws Exception
{
    // hash password with SHA-256 and crop the output to 128-bit for key
    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    digest.update(password.getBytes("UTF-8"));

    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[32];
    System.arraycopy(digest.digest(), 0, keyBytes, 0, keyBytes.length);

    cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
    key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
    spec = getIV();
}

public AlgorithmParameterSpec getIV()
{
    byte[] iv = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, };
    IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec;
    ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

    return ivParameterSpec;
}

public String encrypt(String plainText) throws Exception
{
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, spec);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    String encryptedText = new String(Base64.encode(encrypted, Base64.DEFAULT), "UTF-8");

    return encryptedText;
}
```

Example:  i have the string 093949 and with the code above we get  "b28VNQIxfmlCfLcjQRS7Dw=="

In C# i'm trying to get the same result but i'm doing something wrong, im stucked.
i need the same result in java

C#

```
 public RijndaelManaged GetRijndaelManaged(String secretKey)
    {
        var keyBytes = new byte[16];
        var secretKeyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey);



        Array.Copy(secretKeyBytes, keyBytes, Math.Min(keyBytes.Length, secretKeyBytes.Length));
        return new RijndaelManaged
        {
            Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
            Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7,
            KeySize = 128,
            BlockSize = 128,
            Key = keyBytes,
            IV = keyBytes
        };
    }

    public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] plainBytes, RijndaelManaged rijndaelManaged)
    {
        return rijndaelManaged.CreateEncryptor()
            .TransformFinalBlock(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);
    }

    public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] encryptedData, RijndaelManaged rijndaelManaged)
    {
        return rijndaelManaged.CreateDecryptor()
            .TransformFinalBlock(encryptedData, 0, encryptedData.Length);
    }


    // Encrypts plaintext using AES 128bit key and a Chain Block Cipher and returns a base64 encoded string

    public String Encrypt(String plainText, String key)
    {
        var plainBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(Encrypt(plainBytes, GetRijndaelManaged(key)));
    }


    public String Decrypt(String encryptedText, String key)
    {
        var encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Decrypt(encryptedBytes, GetRijndaelManaged(key)));
    }
```

we call c# method like this:

```
string senhaencrypted = Encrypt(string_tobeencrypt, password);
```

This return for me:  "Nv1V4RIJ1TczqnKGdN8jMA=="    not  "b28VNQIxfmlCfLcjQRS7Dw=="

Please if someone have a idea what its wrong.
Thanks!

Comment: Title says AES-256, comment in code says AES 128bit.

Comment: I try to change to 256 like in java code, but i can't , im really stucked here
i try to convert line by line, because i dont know c# to much like java.

The password is  "1OnePlaceServicesDecryptionKey"

Comment: How can you expect to get the same answer in C# when: 1) you use a different keysize, and 2) you hash the password in Java but not in C#?

Comment: hash em 256bits do you mean ?
Im trying here with the same key size..but have difference yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a port from Java to C# (as far as I can interpret the Java code, being a C# developer).

However, using the plain text `"093949"` and password `"1OnePlaceServicesDecryptionKey"` the code ***does not*** produce `"b28VNQIxfmlCfLcjQRS7Dw=="`. So there is still something wrong. But the code below should be closer to the original, I think.

```
public static string Encrypt(string plainText, string password)
{
    byte[] keyBytes;
    using (SHA256 hash = SHA256.Create())
    {
        keyBytes = hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
    }

    using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
    {
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        aes.Key = keyBytes;
        aes.IV = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        using (ICryptoTransform cryptoTransform = aes.CreateEncryptor())
        {
            byte[] plainBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
            byte[] encryptedBytes = cryptoTransform.TransformFinalBlock(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytes);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer my friend!